# Null response entity with 307 status code in Rest Template

Tags: spring, rest, http, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am trying to use Spring `RestTemplateBuilder` to call a REST web service and POST data. Here is the sample of my code.

```
public HttpHeaders getHttpHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.add("Authorization", "Basic " + authToken);
    requestHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return requestHeaders;
}

public ResponseJson getData(RequestJson requestJson) {
    HttpEntity<RequestJson> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestJson, getHttpHeaders());
    ResponseEntity<ResponseJson> result = restTemplateBuilder.build().postForEntity(PostUrl, entity, ResponseJson.class);
}
```

When I debug this, it gives **status=307** and **body=null** for **ResponseEntity**. But when I call the PostUrl directly with a request body, it creates data with **201 status code**.

May I know how, to figure out this 307 status and why I am getting null response ?

Comment: "All modern browsers will automatically detect the 307 Temporary Redirect response code and process the redirection action to the new URI automatically" Maybe you should also need to handle 307 in your code.

Comment: @Selindek Yeah, but I don't know how to handle this. I am trying to find the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me, using `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` https://lateralcoding.blogspot.com/2018/03/Spring-RestTemplate-AutoRedirect.html